# Reading image file contents to buffer

Tags: c, io, buffer

```
char* full_string;
int size;
FILE* f = fopen(filename,"r");

fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
size = ftell(f);
fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
full_string = malloc(size+1);
fread(full_string,1,size,f);
fclose(f);

full_string[size] = '\0';
```

I'm trying to read the contents of a file into a buffer named "full_string" with the above code, but when I step through in gdb, I find the following is stored in "full_string" instead:

```
full_string = 0xa46df0 "\377\330\377", <incomplete sequence \340>
```

I'm a complete novice in C, so I have no idea how to interpret this problem. It's worth mentioning that the files I'm reading are image files. Most of these images are 50,000 bytes in size or greater. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect to be in `full_string`?  The debugger in trying to interpret it as a character string, but images aren't character strings.  Thus, your *code* may be fine, but your *debugger* may be confused.

Comment: @ScottHunter or just unable to show such a huge string

Comment: A "string" is a bunch of bytes that end with 0, stored in a `char *` (or a `char[]` that decays into a `char *` when passed to things). If you put something other than that very specific format, you're not making a string, you're making a sequence of bytes. GDB doesn't know that you're not making a string, though; how could it? So it assumes it's a string, and errors out when interpreting it as a string, because it's not a string.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I see, I think that clears up the problem. I assumed that the char array wasn't actually holding the data because of the above problem and the fact that strlen() returned 4, but it makes sense if it was being misinterpreted as a string of length 4. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer. Could you read through it and make sure it still explains everything it should?

Comment: Note that per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), footnote 268, p 310: "Setting  the  file  position  indicator  to  end-of-file, as with `fseek(file,  0,  SEEK_END)`,  has undefined behavior for a binary stream ...", and **7.21.9.2  The `fseek` function**, paragraph 3: "... A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`."  Unfortunately, there is no standard-C compliant way to get the size of a file.  `fseek()` works on binary files on Windows and POSIX systems, but it's not truly portable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Then again, for most casual applications, Windows and POSIX are all you need to support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *` doesn't automatically mean string. A string, in C, is a sequence of bytes, stored in a `char *` (or a `char []` that decays into a `char *` when it's passed somewhere, but let's consider those to be the same thing for this answer). That series of bytes has to end with `'\0'`, the null byte, and not contain it at any point inside.

If you open that particular file in a hex editor, you'll probably see something like `FF D8 FF E0 00`, assuming I (a) got the octal-hex conversion right and (b) didn't make any other dumb mistakes. That's valid in a file, but if you try to interpret it as a string -- with `strlen`, for example, or what GDB does -- you won't get the expected value of ~50000 characters, because there's less than ~50000 characters before the first null byte. This also means that terminating your "string" with a `'\0'` is kinda pointless; I mean, it's *not* a string. It's a sequence of bytes.

If the length is important, you'll need to store that alongside it, either in a structure or in another variable, depending on what your requirements are.